# Can we attach debugger in Pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I did the changes as below

```
shared_preload_libraries = $libdir/plugins/plugin_debugger.dll
```

in the file postgresql.conf

But when I restart the service it gets stopped.

Comment: Yes-Thanks- Its pgadmin 4

Comment: I think the path should be `$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll` - there is no "plugin" sub-directory in the `lib` directory - at least not in my Postgres 10 Windows installation

Comment: I have answered the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038611/pgadmin4-enable-debugging