# PgAdmin4 enable debugging

Tags: postgresql, debugging, pgadmin-4

I am unable to enable debugging in pgAdmin4. I have performed the following: 
1. checked $libdir 
2. checked the locatin of plugin_debugger.dll 
3. changed postgresql.conf 
and the database will not restart.

Any suggestions what have I done wrong?

[image: the steps taken]

Comment: I have got a tip to delete postmaster.pid from the data dolder and this solved the issue. Hope that this post will help someone else.

Answer (score 9):

1) Download Postgres installer from [EnterpriseDB website](https://www.enterprisedb.com/enterprisedb-software-downloads), they bundle debugger plugin.

[image]

2) Make an entry in the `postgresql.conf` file,

On Unix like systems,

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.so'
```

On Windows systems,

```
shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/plugin_debugger.dll'
```

3) Restart your Postgres instance.

4) You have to create `pldbgapi` Extension in your maintenance database.

Refer given steps,

[image]

[image]

Click on `Save` button.

5) Goto your `plpgsql` function and right click on it, you will see "Debug" option. 
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. in addition to this.  if you have problem on enabling shared libs,

 under your postgresql install folder (for me c/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/bin), run
pg_config.exe --sharedir This will give you shared folder address.  And in your postgresql.com file set it like

      dynamic_library_path = 'C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/13/share:$libdir'

Comment: out of curiosity, would this help with PostgreSQL role security debugging?  Any chance you guys know which repo contains that source code?