# Debugging in pgAdmin - "list index out of range"

Tags: postgresql, debugging, pgadmin

I am trying to debug function in PostgreSql database using PG Admin Tools. I've done everything like in this topic:
[pgadmin4-enable-debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50038611/pgadmin4-enable-debugging)

Edit postgresql.conf, create extension and so on, but when i am right-click on some function -> Debugging -> Debug i'am getting error:

[image]

The same error appear when i choose ...Debugging -> Set a breakpoint

Comment: there other ways to debug a function, why not share the function and tables with data, so that we can help